IIS AD trust - how IIS validates the user
I have a user logged into domain A and an IIS server in domain B. There is a two-way trust between these domains.
Now, the user from domain A enters the web app hosted on IIS in domain B using windows integrated authentication.
Regardless the NTLM or Kerberos, will the IIS contacts directly with the user's domain "A" to validates the user's ticket, or will it send it to the domain "B" for DC to validate it? Or will it works completely different?
Thanks for clarification.
Currently, using Wireshark on the IIS server, we have found, that the IIS contacts directly the user's AD and not via IIS's parent domain, "B". Now we are not sure if this is error in our trust configuration or we just don't know how IIS and trust works.

The link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/ntlm-overview states that:
"When the NTLM protocol is used, a resource server must take one of the following actions to verify the identity of a computer or user whenever a new access token is needed:
Contact a domain authentication service on the domain controller for the computer's or user's account domain, if the account is a domain account."
So accordingly a user from DomainA logs on the domain A, and then tries to connect to IIS server in DomainB, the IIS server (resource server) will contact a domain controller in UserA domain which is DomainA and this is conformant with your authentication traces. The statement says 'user's or computer's account domain' so the NTLM authentication request may be passed to DomainB Domain Controller. I think when the the DomainB Domain Controller (DomainB DC) is involved, to authenticate the user A, pass thru authentication occurs and the account credentials are securely sent to the DomainA DC.
Another reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/windows-updates-add-new-ntlm-pass-through-authentication-protections states that windows updates have increased NTLM authentication security in scope of NTLM trusted domain authentication communication.
The following may assist for understanding the overall authentication process for different trust types and protocols that are used.
NTLM Auditing should be enabled . Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/audit-domain-controller-ntlmv1#ntlm-auditing
Kerberos logging should be enabled as referenced at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/enable-kerberos-event-logging
Depending on your trust types (Forest Trust, Direct Trust, External Trust, Transitive Trust), OS and patch levels, firewall ports open between domain controllers, the authentication protocols or authentication paths may change. I assume that in your environment NTLM is being used for trust authentication communication. Also pass thru authentication implies NTLM. It can be verified from logs that occur during accessing the IIS application on IIS servers, both domain controllers and clients that access the application.
Kerberos totally follows different paths and has different processes and requirements. In a Kerberos communication for example, the client workstation will be a member of DomainA and when the user logs on to domain A, the user will automatically get a TGT (Ticket Granting Ticket). When the user clicks the client application or accesses the IIS application on a browser, in the background, the user will request a Ticket Granting Service (TGS) ticket from DomainA domain controller for IIS server in domain B.
In NTLM such a ticket request and process is not defined.
I hope these clarify some points.
